How to restore mongoDB dump data from local instance to an azure cosmos db for mongo account
i have a compressed .gz file which is the mongodb dump file and i want to restore the data in the azure cosmos db for mongodb account.
i am using the mongorestore command:
mongorestore --uri="connection string" --gzip --archive="path to the file"

error:comparing auth version of dump directory and auth server (Timestamp) Failed: error getting auth version of the server. (CommandNotSupported) command getParameter not supported.

using gzip because i want to handle the decompression while executing the command because if i uncompress it first the uncompressed data will be closed to 70GB.
P.S: This command worked in the local instance for mongodb any suggestion why i am not able to do it ?

You're encountering this error because Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB does not support the getParameter command, which is used by mongorestore to check the authentication schema version of the server.

so any suggestions how can i tackle this??
